# All object property is not empty javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, express, undefined

How to check the following object, make sure every property is not equal to undefined, null or empty string?

```
userObj = {
        name: {
            first: req.body.first,
            last: req.body.last
        },
        location: {
          city: req.body.city
        },
        phone: req.body.phone
    }
```

I can check req.body one by one like if(req.body.first) but that's too tedious if I have many params.

Comment: do you need a check before assignment or after? what about zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [**Array.prototype.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method over `Object.values()` to implement this in a recursive way:

```
function isThereAnUndefinedValue(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj).some(function(v) {
    if (typeof v === 'object'){
      if(v.length && v.length>0){
          return v.some(function(el){
              return (typeof el === "object") ? isThereAnUndefinedValue(el) : (el!==0 && el!==false) ? !el : false;
          });
      }
      return isThereAnUndefinedValue(v);
    }else {
      console.log(v);
      return (v!==0 && v!==false) ? !v : false;
    }
  });
}
```

In the following function we will:

- Loop over our `object` values.
- Check if the iterated value is an `object` we call the function recursively with this value.
- Otherwise we will just check if this is a truthy value or not.

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo:

```js
userObj = {
  name: {
    first: "req.body.first",
    last: [5, 10, 0, 40]
  },
  location: {
    city: "req.body.city"
  },
  phone: "req.body.phone"
}

function isThereAnUndefinedValue(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj).some(function(v) {
    if (typeof v === 'object'){
      if(v.length && v.length>0){
          return v.some(function(el){
              return (typeof el === "object") ? isThereAnUndefinedValue(el) : (el!==0 && el!==false) ? !el : false;
          });
      }
      return isThereAnUndefinedValue(v);
    }else {
      console.log(v);
      return (v!==0 && v!==false) ? !v : false;
    }
  });
}

console.log(isThereAnUndefinedValue(userObj));
```

You will get a function that validates every object and its sub objects in a recursive way.

Comment: is this the way to go to validate resquest object? how about array of object?

Comment: I built this upon the example you provided, as it has only objects, but if you want I can refactor it.

Comment: @JessieAnderson I updated the code, it takes into consideration any type of object now including arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To check for truthy values (values other than `false`, `''`, `0`, `null`, `undefined`):

```js
const hasOnlyTruthyValues = obj => Object.values(obj).every(Boolean);
```

Example:

```js
const hasOnlyTruthyValues = obj => Object.values(obj).every(Boolean);
const object = {
  a: '12',
  b: 12,
  c: ''
};

console.log(hasOnlyTruthyValues(object));
```

The example you posted (`if (res.body.first) ...`) also checks for a truthy value. If you want to allow `false` and `0` (which are falsy, but you didn't mention them in your question), use:

```js
const hasOnlyAllowedValues = obj => Object.values(obj).every(v => v || v === 0 || v === false);
```

Comment: No, it won't. Can't you call it like `hasOnlyTruthyValues(req.body)`? Can `req.body` contain nested objects?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a simple validator for yourself like function below

```js
var body = {
  a: 1,
  b: 3
};
var keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];


function validate(body, keys) {
  for (var i in keys) {
    if (!body[keys[i]]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(validate(body, keys));
```

Comment: what about nested objects ?

Comment: @marvel308 I think he want to validate body of a request and in this example he only need to validate `req.body` which does not have nested object

Answer (score 0):

In your post you use:

```
    if(req.body.first)
```

I don't know if you are checking req and body before hand, but this should be:

```
    if ( typeof req == "object" && typeof req.body == "object"
    && req.body.first ) {
```

That is a safer way to check before use.

Or, if you want to embed in the object:

```
    function fnTest(a,b,c) {
        return (typeof a == "object" && typeof b == "object" && c) ? c : "";
    };

    userObj = {name:{
                first: fnTest(req, req.body, req.body.first)
                ,last: fnTest(req,req.body, req.body.last)
               },location:{
                city: fnTest(req,req.body,req.body.city)
               },phone: fnTest(req.body.phone)
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following validator to check, it works for a nested object as well

```js
function objectValidator(obj){
 let ret = true;
 for(property in obj){
  //console.log(property, obj[property], typeof obj[property]);
  if(typeof obj[property] == "object"){
   if(obj[property] instanceof Array){
    ret = (ret & true);
   }
   else if(obj[property] == null){
    ret = false;
   }
   else{
    ret = (ret & objectValidator(obj[property]));
   }
  }
  else if(typeof obj[property] == "string"){
   if(obj[property] == ""){
    ret = false;
   }
  }
  else if(typeof obj[property] == "undefined"){
   ret = false;
  }
 }
 return ret;
}

let a = {
 b : 1,
 c :{
  d: 2,
  e: [3, 4],
  f : ""
 }
}
console.log(objectValidator(a));
```